# How can i repeat a Selenium Test for a list of values?

Tags: automation, repeat, selenium-ide

I have a selenium test that i need to repeat, but each test i need to use a different value and different linkText target. Is there a way to do this? Included is a screenshot with the highlighted parts i need to change each time i run the test.

Eager to learn. Your help/advice would be much appreciated.

[Screenshot of Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dORUl.png)